# How to use SymPy by PyCall (no using SymPy)

Tags: julia, sympy

How to use SymPy (by PyCall) for solve equation, case:
solve(x^2 - 4, x).

Comment: Why? Why would you do this?
SymPy.jl  is loverly.

Answer (score 4):

There are other ways, but this will work:

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> @pyimport sympy

julia> x = sympy.Symbol("x")
PyObject x

julia> convert(Function, sympy.solve)(pyeval("x**2-2", x=x))
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 PyObject -sqrt(2)
 PyObject sqrt(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this ;)

I modified your answer and it's working:

`sympy.solve(pyeval("x**2 - 4", x = x), x)`